# Merging Array of Objects with same key

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array as under

Data =

```
 [
  {
    "field": "Classifications.LEV_2_HIER_NME",
    "value": "Treasury Note",
    "aggregates": {
      "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
        "sum": "5,981,210,920.0000"
      }
    },
    "Items": [
      {
        "field": "Classifications.LEV_1_HIER_NME",
        "value": "Treasury 1",
        "aggregates": {
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
            "sum": "5,981,210,920.0000"
          }
        },
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "field": "Classifications.LEV_1_HIER_NME",
        "value": "Treasure 1",
        "aggregates": {
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
            "sum": "5,981,210,920.0000"
          }
        },
        "Items": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "field": "Classifications.LEV_2_HIER_NME",
    "value": "Treasury Note",
    "aggregates": {
      "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
        "sum": "8,981,210,920.0000"
      }
    },
    "Items": [
      {
        "field": "Classifications.LEV_1_HIER_NME",
        "value": "Treasury 1",
        "aggregates": {
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
            "sum": "8,981,210,920.0000"
          }
        },
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "field": "Classifications.LEV_1_HIER_NME",
        "value": "Treasure 1",
        "aggregates": {
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
            "sum": "8,981,210,920.0000"
          }
        },
        "Items": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Data array has two objects. I want to merge the aggregate property of second object in the first one.

something like this:

```
[
  {
    "field": "Classifications.LEV_2_HIER_NME",
    "value": "Treasury Note",
    "aggregates": {
      "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
        "sum": "5,981,210,920.0000"
      },
      "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT_1": {
        "sum": "8,981,210,920.0000"
      }
    },
    "Items": [
      {
        "field": "Classifications.LEV_1_HIER_NME",
        "value": "Treasury 1",
        "aggregates": {
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
            "sum": "5,981,210,920.0000"
          },
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT_1": {
            "sum": "8,981,210,920.0000"
          }
        },
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "field": "Classifications.LEV_1_HIER_NME",
        "value": "Treasure 1",
        "aggregates": {
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT": {
            "sum": "5,981,210,920.0000"
          },
          "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT_1": {
            "sum": "8,981,210,920.0000"
          }
        },
        "Items": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

is there any way to implement this. Level of nesting is dynamic but all the objects will have same structure.

Comment: _"is there any way to implement this"_ - yes, but it would be better to share your attempt as a [mcve]. Then we can help with where you're stuck.

Comment: There's no JSON in your "question"

Comment: @Andreas it could be, but the `DATA =` at the beginning makes me think not...

Comment: @Andreas I have modified for readability

Comment: Please also note that the `aggregates` property name is misspelled, which you might want to fix depending on where you receive this data from

Comment: JSON is a string. What you're asking is not possible with a string. Hence this has to be _not JSON_ to work... - So why the extra step?

Comment: @Andreas I need to modify the data to use it in grid but have no other way than to do it in client side

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhb3kl

Comment: It looks like the way you're merging the key-value pairs inside the `aggregates` key, is by adding a _1 behind the repeated field of `VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT`. Is that what you want? @Amit

Comment: Yes u r right @prashin jeevaganth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge the 2 objects inside the array into 1, this involves

Step 1. extracting the required elements from the 2nd object

Step 2. adding it into the object of the first.

Suppose the array is read into a variable `data`, then this is 1 way we can extract it in Step 1.

```
let {
  aggregates: {
      VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT
  },
} = data[1];
```

The value paired to the `VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT` key of the 2nd object is stored inside a variable `VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT`. You can read more about Object Destructuring in Javascript.

For Step 2, we will add the value into the first variable. We can also think of objects to have similar syntax to maps, hence this is 1 way we can do it.

```
let first = data[0];
first["aggregates"]["VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT_1"] = VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT;
```

Extracting and adding the elements this way forms a shallow copy of the variable `VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT`, now as a value of  `VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT_1`. Consequently, it is not advisable to delete the actual object in position 1 from the original array. Instead, it might be better to return the new object `first` in a new array.

```
const result = [first];
return result;
```

Comment: Hi Prashin . Thanks for the solution. I am trying to implement the same but facing difficulty as nested level is dynamic.

Comment: Could you elaborate or maybe add an example to illustrate the "dynamic" restriction?

Comment: Hi Prashin . Thanks for the solution. I am trying to implement the same but facing difficulty as nested level is dynamic. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhb3kl?file=src%2Fsummary-grid%2Fdata-modifier.service.ts in data-modifier.service.ts I am trying to achieve the same. Although I am able to get to the lowest level of nesting but not able to update the same level for [first]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhb3kl?file=src%2Fsummary-grid%2Fdata-modifier.service.ts

Comment: @Amit I still don't quite get what you mean, and I don't know how your application works too. Do you have a rather complicated nesting example that you would like to merge? Maybe you can also provide that expected output.

Comment: If you will check the console of the shared demo Inquiry Data is the actual Data which I want to merge

Comment: let me create a diifferent sample and share

Comment: I am able to achieve it @Prashin

Comment: Marking as accepted answer as I have used Object Destructuring with recursion to achieve the task